# Is it possible to detect that a thread was context-switched in Linux [suspended]?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, pthreads

I am writing a multithreaded program in C/C++ which target is a Linux box.

Is possible to detect when one of the threads gets context switched (i.e., suspended)? Note, I am not interested to know if the thread is still alive, I want to know if it is currently running or not.

Comment: How do you contemplate using this information? Do you want to find out from another thread in the same executable, or from a different process?

Comment: From a different thread. I want to check from thread 0 whether thread 1...N are currently running or not. I am implementing a work stealing algorithm.

Comment: Such information would be stale by the time it was received.

Comment: I think you can't. What is the reason why you need to know this?

Comment: @JohnTortugo: For implement work stealing algorithms you should operate with *task queues* on threads, not with *context swithing* points. See, e.g.,  implementation on .NET: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2009/06/26/work-stealing-in-net-4-0.aspx.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: thanks for the pointers. I am doing research on this topic, so I am free to try any idea =)

Comment: I'm not very knowledgable about the topic, but the book [Understanding the Linux Kernel](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000028.do), chapter 3, goes pretty in depth into how Linux manages processes and thread, including the structures the kernel uses to track these things. While probably not available from user-space, you might be able to create a kernel driver that allows a user-space program to query or receive notifications when a specific thread/process has changed state. (I have nothing to do with the book or O'Reilly, BTW, I just own it)

Answer (score 0):

You can  use the STAT column in the ps output to get an idea of what exactly the state the process/thread is in.

In linux,threads are nothing but processes that share same code,data segment and heap segment.

An example output of the ps command and how to interpret can be found at 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18474/what-does-this-process-stat-indicates

Comment: How is that related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

> Is possible to detect when one of the threads gets context switched (i.e., suspended)?

As for your question if it is possible or not - It think it is possible. At least SystemTap (https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) can do it.

SystemTap has a script that let a user see context switches for a certain PID (https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/profiling/sched_switch.stp):

```
probe scheduler.ctxswitch
{
    if (target_pid != 0
        && next_pid != target_pid
        && prev_pid != target_pid)
            next

    if (target_name != ""
        && prev_task_name != target_name
        && next_task_name != target_name)
            next

    printf("%-16s%5d %5d %5d:%5d:%s ==> %5d:%5d:%s %-16s\n",prev_task_name,
        task_cpu(prev_task),gettimeofday_ns(),prev_pid,prev_priority,state_calc(prevtsk_state),next_pid,
        next_priority,state_calc(nexttsk_state),next_task_name)
}
```

As far as I know SystemTap compiles STP files, put then in Linux kernel and shows you information.

I am not aware how to get this information in user space and in your C++ program. However it seems to be also possible (http://netsplit.com/tracing-on-linux):

> Secondly trace events are usable from userspace! we don’t need to
>   write kernel modules to be able to hook into them, but obviously we
>   can only read data this way

So it would be great if you can uncover it and later on answer your own question.